# Issue using ANTLR4 PLSQL grammar to .cs file in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, plsql, antlr4

I converted ANTLR **PLSQL.G4** grammar file to *PLSQLParser.cs* and *PLSQLLexer.cs* with the help of C# target for ANTLR4. Please refer the [link](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs).

I used the below mentioned command line command to convert grammar file to .cs code.

```
java -jar antlr-4.5.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp PLSQL.g4
```

It generated the below mentioned 6 files, namely.

- PLSQL.tokens
- PLSQLBaseListener.cs
- PLSQLLexer.cs
- PLSQLLexer.tokens
- PLSQLListener.cs
- PLSQLParser.cs

I added those files to my C# project also added the ANTLR runtime for C# (**Antlr4.Runtime.dll**) as a reference to my project.

Finally I tried to build my C# project, but it showing **36 build errors**. That too in the file PLSQLParser.cs and PLSQLLexer.cs. Please refer the below mentioned errors.

1. The name '_input' does not exist in the current context
2. The name 'setChannel' does not exist in the current context
3. The name 'HIDDEN' does not exist in the current context

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition.

Please help me to correct those build errors.

Thanks,
Sivaprakash.

Comment: Please, post the grammar code.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the G4-File is built for the Antler-Version you are using to convert from *.G4 to *.CS

The "xxx doesn't exist error" is usually that kind of mistake.